# unable to get product price in custom file magento

Tags: magento, get, categories, product

Hi i am new to magento and i need to get the products from a particular category

for this i have use

```
<?php 
$id1=4;
$category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id1);
$collection1 = $category1->getProductCollection();
$collection1->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection1->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$collection1->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$collection1->addAttributeToSelect('producturl');
$collection1->addAttributeToSelect('prlce');

$products1 = $collection1->getItems();
$_helper1 = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?> 

                                                <?php foreach ($products1 as $product1){  ?>

    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($product1->getPrice()) ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

in this it is showing the name , image and url but when i am trying to echo price it doenot show anyhing.Please suggest me where i am doing mistake

Comment: You also have a typo here: `$collection1->addAttributeToSelect('prlce');`.  Should be `'price'` not `'prlce'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
<?php

// Test Params
$cat_id   = 4;
$store_id = 1;

// Load Category
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);

// Load Category Products
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection();

// Iterate Through Product Collection
foreach ($categoryProducts as $categoryProduct)
{
    // Load Product At Specified Store Id
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->setStoreId($store_id)
               ->load($categoryProduct->getId());

    // Debug
    print_r($product->getData());

    // Get Price (e.g.)
    echo 'Product Price: '. $product->getPrice()
}

?>
```